# While adding an id to a specific innerpage not working in chrome

Tags: html, css

Im stuck with a problem, while adding a link to another inner page, not working in chrome, but in firefox working perfect. Please check the code below

Here is the footer link in index.html

```
     <div class="related_link"><div class="related_link_link">

                 <table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <td width="107" height="20" style="text-align:left;"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
        <td width="116" style="text-align:left;"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></td>
       <td width="113" style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html#financhk">Financial Summary</a></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
          <td height="20" style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html">About  Us</a></td>
         <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html#visionchk">Our Vision</a></td>
           <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html#invstrchk">Investor Relation</a></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td height="20" style="text-align:left;"><a href="promoters.html">Promoters</a></td>
          <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html#dirchk">Directors</a></td>
       <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html#chairchk">Chairman Message</a></td>
         </tr>
     <tr>
            <td height="20" style="text-align:left;"><a href="medical_services.html">Medical Services</a></td>
            <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html#visionchk">Our Mission</a></td>
           <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="#">Legal Disclaimer</a></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
           <td height="20" style="text-align:left;"><a href="enquiry.html">Enquiry</a></td>
         <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="about_us.html#prjctglchk">Project At Glance</a></td>
           <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="sitemap.xml">Sitemap</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td height="20" style="text-align:left;"><a href="contact_us.html">Contact us</a></td>
       <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="route_map.html">Route Map</a></td>
        <td style="text-align:left;"></td>
          </tr>
               </table></div>






                         </div>
```

here is the target link in aboutus.html

```
  </div><a name="chairchk"></a>
```

The target link is inside a slider. This working fine in firefox, but in chrome, the page directed to aboutus.html. Please help.....

Comment: where is `<a href="about_us.html#financhk">` is it in the about_us .html? if yes try this instead `a href="#financhk">`

Comment: <a href="about_us.html#financhk"> is in the index page....its working perfect in firefox, but in chrome while clicking, ill get a blink of the section then after its redirecting to aboutus.html...@imsiso

Comment: I know but this is where the problem is (I think). So did you tried that? (`<a href="#financhk">`)

Comment: ya..i tried it..but the page not directing to aboutus.html....:-(...@imsiso

Comment: sorry I miss understood your question and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

try putting `<a id="financhk">`

Comment: It should work if it is not you r doing smething wrong. Can u updat you question with some more details. Like your markup of both pages.

Comment: im herewith adding the link http://www.genesishospital.in/trial . Please check the index page footer link redirect to about us mini navs in firefox and chrome....

Comment: didn't get you. Is this the same markup we were talking about. I mean in your question. Cuz the markup here doesn't seem to contain the url hash.

Comment: Anyways for me the click navigates me to aboutus.html on all browsers. You haven't changed name to id yet and why are you using a blank anchor tag instead of the containing div? set id=financhk for the containing div. And It is hard debuggin this way. Try to isolate the link and its destination and upload it please.